What is this blister in the paint on the interior of my foundation wall?
Does anyone know what this could be?  It appeared on the base of my basement wall.


"It appeared" How fast? Over a couple years, could be something not so bad. In three minutes, you'll probably find out what caused it before tonight when it breaks through and slithers in....

Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

That's probably a place where water has come through the wall.
